# Throttle unauthenticated (no API Key) requests on API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'd like to provide a free tier for my API and allow new users to test drive it without having to sign up for an API key.

Is there a way that I can set a limit/quota and throttle requests that have no api key on API Gateway?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, essentially there are two places where you can configure your throttling options:

1. In usage plans. You link API Key to usage plan and configure method request to require API key.
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html
2. n stage settings you can configure default throttling method - this will be applicable to any request (no API key required).
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html

what you are looking is 2.

by the way, very important moment - be aware that API Keys are not a security mechanism - you should not use API for authentication purposes.

Comment: using 2 would mean limiting access for user's who have signed up as well

Comment: i think in that case you'd better go with a separate stage (i.e /uat/) for your test users; or if you prefer the same stage then to have distinct resources for requests requiring API-keys (i.e. /method) and not requiring API-keys (i.e. /method/uat  or /uat/method ) and configure each of these accordingly. moreover, i don't think you'll be able to configure "optional" API-keys on precisely the same resource / method - as this flag is binary (yes/no).

Comment: Coming here from way in the future. If  you require an api key and make that key public and required that should give you the effect of having unauthenticated users limited by the usage plan. That fact that the key is public doesnt matter because you want to limit anyone who connects to the api.